# Learning to simplify for calculus and differential equations: what else than basic stuff?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'll make a long story short: I started taking math seriously much too late, so now I'm pretty  good  at calculus/differential equations, etc , but I suck at the algebra which is needed in order to simplify and etc, and that makes it almost impossible for me to solve assignments that I could otherwise easily do, simply because I sometimes *have* to simplify before I can take the derivative for example.

Any site or youtube vid you can point me towards that teaches thoroughly (from the basic to the more advanced) the art of simplifying (including factorising, fraction rules, exponential rules)? Hopefully with a focus on calculus?

Comment: There's no royal road to calculus.

Comment: I'm probably better at calculus than you. This is not about calculus, it's about algebra. Well done missing the point entirely. Maybe you should try and find a royal road to simple common sense?

Comment: @danni 1. Ouch!     2. I have found the answers given to the various questions in math.stackexchange to be extremely helpful in the very area in which you seem to be seeking help. There is a lot of ingeniousness to be mined here!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for years of elementry mathematics in a single course. For lower level stuff, Khan Academy is very thorough but a tad slow.